# Как принять и прочитать массив строк при помощи Spring 3?

Tags: spring, json, java

Здравствуйте. Как принять и прочитать массив строк при помощи `Spring 3`? В качестве `JSON`-запроса выступает массив строк. Выглядит он так:

```
["cnh","dfd","asd"]
```

Вот то, что принимает на сервере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteelements.form")
@ResponseBody
public String deleteElements(/* ??? */) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteelements.form")
@ResponseBody
public String deleteElements(@RequestBody String elements[]) {
}
```

Разумеется, для этого Spring должен видеть библиотеку Jackson.
В случае с мавеном добавьте зависимости:

```
 <!-- Jackson JSON -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Или просто киньте соответствующие jar-ники в WEB-INF/lib.

Кроме того, у входящего HTTP-запроса заголовок `Content-type` должен соответствовать `application/json`.

Comment: Я еще добавлю. Можно также вот так:  

    @RequestBody ArrayList<String> str

Comment: можно даже `HttpEntity<String[]>`. Spring MVC 3 в этом плане вообще много вкусного дает. [Вот, что можно подавать](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments) на вход методам контроллера.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD** На самом деле интеграция с Jackson реализована в Spring (`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`), достаточно только подключить его библиотеки, см. ответ @Nofate.

---

Для того, чтобы заработал вариант @Nofate, необходимо сначала добавить конвертер, так как в Спринге нет конвертера для массивов строк. [На SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019162/custom-httpmessageconverter-with-responsebody-to-do-json-things) показывается, как это можно сделать (кофигурирование вроде бы должно быть упрощено в Spring 3.1M1): вкратце это просто реализация интерфейса/абстрактного класса конвертера и его регистрация.

В самом конвертере можно использовать, к примеру, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), для преобразования.

Если это только один раз нужно, то можно сделать и напрямую:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteelements.form")
@ResponseBody
public String deleteElements(@RequestBody byte[] data) {
    // делает то же самое, что делали бы конвертере,
    // скармливаем Jackson'у байтовый массив
}
```

Comment: А разве Jackson автоматически не используется, если приходит JSON?

Comment: Используется. Нужно только кинуть его в зависимости/библиотеки. Если Jackson лежит в проекте, спринг сам все сообразит и распарсит вам JSON в массив.

Comment: @Nofate , подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Если пользуетесь maven-ом:

      <!-- Jackson JSON -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
 
     <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Если не пользуетесь, просто киньте jar-ники в WEB-INF/lib к прочим библиотекам.

Comment: Ха! РАБОТАЕТ! Отправьте комментарий последний в ответ. Я приму его. @Nofate , Ваш вариант более красивый. Только еще не хватает того, что надо устанавливать в `header`: `Content-Type` : 'application/json;'. Тогда Спринг автоматически парсит.

Comment: Вариант @yozh тоже красивый. Тут уже на любителя.  
  
СПАСИБО ВСЕМ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ!!!

Comment: Конечно парсит, куда ему деваться. Таким же образом, кстати, можно парсить JSON в объекты и обратно.

Comment: И правда, есть же `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. Недоглядел.